# Trying to use Php-MySQL to retrieve video URL from database and display it on browser

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, url

I'm stuck on a php issue where I'm trying to access a url I stored in a local database (stored on a MAMP server) and display it. The URL is a video file on a server and the idea is that the video is retrieved from the url on the database and shown on a browser (preferably on auto-play). For some reason, the php script won't show the table contents at all. I'm kind of new to sql. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks
This is the db table:
[media](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1c2AX.png)

This is my code:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "media";
$password = "mysqluser";
$dbname = "media";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

// sql to display a record
$sql = "SELECT * FROM media";


if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record dislayed successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error showing record" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
```

?>

Comment: What is your table name, is it media too? because I read media as your db name

Comment: It doesn't look like you're echoing anything out of the database..

Comment: What's the output at the moment? You won't be getting any database output as @Mattigins pointed out, but you should be getting one of your echos or your die statement, or a PHP error message (if you have error reporting on in your php.ini file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are new to mysql, I think you should echo the url out and put it maybe a HTML5 video player.

e.g

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "media";
$password = "mysqluser";
$dbname = "media";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

// sql to display a record
$sql = "SELECT * FROM media";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$data = $result->fetch_assoc();
$video = $data['video']; // if video is the column name

echo"<video width='320' height='240' controls>
<source src='".$video."' type='video/mp4'>
</video>
";
?>
```

N/B: The example if for mp4 videos

Comment: Thank you for the help. Your solution worked. I really appreciate it :)